# Using a Class Function without an Object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, file-io, static

I remember doing something like this in Java but that was a while back, I know you can call a function from a class without an object. But I'm not sure how to implement it in the header and implementation files for the class. Basically I've been working on a function that reads a file in and set the variables in certain indexes of an array. I know static objects cannot access non-static objects. But I remember doing something like this before.

```
int Person::readFile(Person person[], int counter) {
ifstream infile;
infile.open("People.txt");

while(!infile.eof()) {
    infile >> person[counter].firstName >> person[counter].lastName >> person[counter].age >> person[counter].gender;
    counter++;
}

infile.close();

return counter; 
}
```

I want it to read in the first 4 file elements and set them to the current index, then go to the next array index. I was going to make it a separate function, but the criteria is to have everything in the header and implementation files. It runs fine when I use

```
Person people[MAX_SIZE];
int i = 0;
people[i].readFile(people, i);
```

Which is okay, because I'm sure that's acceptable. But I want it to be like either of these lines.

```
readFile(people, i);
Person::readFile(people, i);
```

I feel like it would not make sense to use an object to set the array of objects' variables. Thank you to anyone that comments, and if there's a better way please let me know.

Comment: For you to be able to do that, the function must be declared `static`.

Comment: Make `Person::readFile` static.

Comment: and take out readFile() from Person class. Create a separate class PersonFiller for this. It's more correct by OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Static member functions can be accessed without using an object of the corresponding class type.  Static member functions can only access static member variables.

Comment: and other `static` member functions.